Button dissapears after click it
Im making a simple web app using google app script for a simple time attendance. my problem is after clicking the submit button to check or verify the email . the time in button disappear after 2 seconds. or if not press it will not function. can anyone guide me the correct direction for this
CODE GS SCRIPT
// Function to include external CSS or JavaScript files in the HTML output
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

// Function to check employee details
function checkEmployee(email) {
  var empSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Employee list');
  if (!empSheet) {
    return { status: 'Error', message: 'Employee list not found.' };
  }

  var empData = empSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var authorizedEmployee = empData.find(row => row[3].trim().toLowerCase() === email.trim().toLowerCase());

  if (!authorizedEmployee) {
    return { status: 'Unauthorized', message: 'Employee not found.' };
  }

  var firstName = authorizedEmployee[0];
  var lastName = authorizedEmployee[1];
  var lob = authorizedEmployee[2];
  var currentDateTime = new Date().toLocaleString();

  return { 
    status: 'Success', 
    firstName: firstName, 
    lastName: lastName, 
    lob: lob, 
    currentDateTime: currentDateTime,
    email: email
  };
}

// Function to handle form submission
function onFormSubmit(email, location, action) {
  Logger.log('onFormSubmit called with email: ' + email + ', location: ' + location + ', action: ' + action);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Attendance');
  var empSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Employee list');
  
  if (!sheet || !empSheet) {
    Logger.log('Sheet or Employee list not found');
    return { status: 'Error', message: 'Sheet or Employee list not found.' };
  }

  var empData = empSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log('Employee Data: ' + JSON.stringify(empData));

  var authorizedEmployee = empData.find(row => row[3].trim().toLowerCase() === email.trim().toLowerCase());
  
  if (!authorizedEmployee) {
    Logger.log('Employee not found for email: ' + email);
    return { status: 'Unauthorized', message: 'Employee not found.' };
  }

  var firstName = authorizedEmployee[0];
  var lastName = authorizedEmployee[1];
  var lob = authorizedEmployee[2];
  var currentDateTime = new Date().toLocaleString();

  if (action === 'TIME IN') {
    var newRow = [firstName, lastName, lob, email, location, currentDateTime, '', ''];
    sheet.appendRow(newRow);

    // Send email confirmation for TIME IN
    sendConfirmationEmail(email, firstName, lastName, currentDateTime, '', '');

    return { 
      status: 'Success', 
      message: 'Time In recorded successfully.', 
      buttonLabel: 'TIME OUT', 
      firstName: firstName, 
      lastName: lastName, 
      lob: lob, 
      currentDateTime: currentDateTime 
    };
  } 
  
  else if (action === 'TIME OUT') {
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var rowData = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 8).getValues()[0];
    if (rowData[3] === email && rowData[6] === '') {
      var endTime = currentDateTime;
      sheet.getRange(lastRow, 7).setValue(endTime);
      var totalHours = calculateTotalHours(rowData[5], endTime);
      sheet.getRange(lastRow, 8).setValue(totalHours);

      // Send confirmation email with details
      sendConfirmationEmail(email, firstName, lastName, rowData[5], endTime, totalHours);

      return { 
        status: 'Success', 
        message: 'Time Out recorded successfully.', 
        buttonLabel: 'TIME IN', 
        firstName: firstName, 
        lastName: lastName, 
        lob: lob, 
        currentDateTime: currentDateTime,
        timeIn: rowData[5],
        timeOut: endTime,
        totalHours: totalHours
      };
    } else {
      return { 
        status: 'Error', 
        message: 'No valid Time In found for today.', 
        buttonLabel: 'TIME OUT', 
        firstName: firstName, 
        lastName: lastName, 
        lob: lob, 
        currentDateTime: currentDateTime 
      };
    }
  } 
  
  else {
    return { 
      status: 'Error', 
      message: 'Invalid action.', 
      buttonLabel: 'TIME OUT', 
      firstName: firstName, 
      lastName: lastName, 
      lob: lob, 
      currentDateTime: currentDateTime 
    };
  }
}

// Function to calculate total hours between two timestamps
function calculateTotalHours(startTime, endTime) {
  var start = new Date(startTime);
  var end = new Date(endTime);
  var diff = (end - start) / 1000; // difference in seconds
  var hours = Math.floor(diff / 3600);
  var minutes = Math.floor((diff % 3600) / 60);
  return hours + '.' + (minutes / 60).toFixed(2).slice(-2);
}

// Function to send confirmation email
function sendConfirmationEmail(email, firstName, lastName, timeIn, timeOut, totalHours) {
  var subject = 'Time Tracking Confirmation';
  var message = 'Dear ' + firstName + ' ' + lastName + ',\n\n' +
                'Your time tracking has been recorded.\n\n' +
                (timeIn ? 'Time In: ' + timeIn + '\n' : '') +
                (timeOut ? 'Time Out: ' + timeOut + '\n' : '') +
                (totalHours ? 'Total Hours: ' + totalHours + '\n' : '') +
                'Thank you.';
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
}

// Function to handle GET requests (used for HTML content)
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page')
      .evaluate()
      .setTitle('Attendance Form')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

// Function to get the last entry for a user to determine the button label
function getLastEntry(email) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Attendance');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var lastEntry = data.reverse().find(row => row[3] === email);
  
  if (lastEntry) {
    if (lastEntry[6] === '') {
      return { status: 'TIME IN' };
    } else {
      return { status: 'TIME OUT' };
    }
  }
  return { status: 'TIME IN' }; // Default to TIME IN if no previous entry
}

Page.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>
  <style>
    #buttonContainer {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    #timeInButton, #timeOutButton {
      flex: 1;
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>ENFRAUSA WAH BIOMETRICS</h2>
  <div>
    <label for="email">Enter your Gmail:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
    <button id="submitEmailButton" onclick="submitEmail()">Submit</button>
    <br>
    <div id="employeeDetails"></div>
    <br>
    <select id="location" style="display:none;">
      <option value="WAH">Work at Home (WAH)</option>
      <option value="ONSITE">On-site</option>
      <option value="MAKATI">Makati</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <div id="buttonContainer">
      <button id="timeInButton" onclick="submitTime('TIME IN')">TIME IN</button>
      <button id="timeOutButton" onclick="submitTime('TIME OUT')">TIME OUT</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    function submitEmail() {
      var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showEmployeeDetails).checkEmployee(email);
    }

    function showEmployeeDetails(response) {
      var detailsDiv = document.getElementById('employeeDetails');
      var locationSelect = document.getElementById('location');

      if (response.status === 'Unauthorized') {
        detailsDiv.innerHTML = '<p>' + response.message + '</p>';
        locationSelect.style.display = 'none';
      } else if (response.status === 'Success') {
        detailsDiv.innerHTML = '<p>Full Name: ' + response.firstName + ' ' + response.lastName + '</p>' +
                               '<p>LOB: ' + response.lob + '</p>' +
                               '<p>Current Time: ' + response.currentDateTime + '</p>';
        locationSelect.style.display = 'block';

        // Ensure buttons are visible
        document.getElementById('timeInButton').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('timeOutButton').style.display = 'block';

        // Check last entry to update button labels if needed
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(entry) {
          if (entry.status === 'TIME IN') {
            document.getElementById('timeInButton').style.display = 'none';
          } else {
            document.getElementById('timeInButton').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('timeOutButton').style.display = 'block';
          }
        }).getLastEntry(response.email);
      }
    }

    function submitTime(action) {
      var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
      var location = document.getElementById('location').value;

      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(response) {
        var detailsDiv = document.getElementById('employeeDetails');
        if (action === 'TIME IN') {
          detailsDiv.innerHTML = '<p>' + response.message + '</p>' +
                                 '<p>Full Name: ' + response.firstName + ' ' + response.lastName + '</p>' +
                                 '<p>LOB: ' + response.lob + '</p>' +
                                 '<p>Time In: ' + response.currentDateTime + '</p>';
        } else if (action === 'TIME OUT') {
          detailsDiv.innerHTML = '<p>' + response.message + '</p>' +
                                 '<p>Full Name: ' + response.firstName + ' ' + response.lastName + '</p>' +
                                 '<p>LOB: ' + response.lob + '</p>' +
                                 '<p>Time In: ' + (response.timeIn || 'N/A') + '</p>' +
                                 '<p>Time Out: ' + (response.timeOut || 'N/A') + '</p>';
        }
      }).onFormSubmit(email, location, action);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>

already revised the code block for last entry probably it is the main suspect but still having problems

Welcome to Stack Overflow. See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

The code line that make dissapears the button is
document.getElementById('timeInButton').style.display = 'none'

The quick fix is to remove this line.
